# 3-heap max heap

Tags: heaps

I have this 3 heap max heap that I need to write the array for it, but I'm not sure how. Would it just be

20,18,13,15,11,12,16,10,9,11,13,2,9?

[image]

Comment: I think you just have to add the `10 1` in the end.

Comment: yea I did that but it was wrong

Comment: Otherwise I don't know what is "the array for it". I understand it as the array implementation of a ternary heap, as described here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be Just the [Level Order Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search_/_level_order) of the tree, In this case, it is 20,18,13,15,11,12,16,10,9,11,13,2,9,10,1.

More generally for a generalized d-heap, the items may be viewed as the nodes in a complete d-ary tree, listed in breadth-first traversal order: the item at position $0$ of the array (using zero-based numbering) forms the root of the tree, the items at positions 1 through d are its children, the next $d^2$ items are its grandchildren, etc. Thus, the parent of the item at position $i$ (for any $i > 0$) is the item at position $⌊(i − 1)/d⌋$ and its children are the items at positions $d\cdot i + 1$ through $d\cdot i + d$.

Comment: thank you! I think I entered some numbers wrong.